# Database query on a specific row

Tags: android

I am building a blood bank database app. Where I will take some info along with blood type. I store the blood type as "INTEGER NOT NULL" with 1, 2,....,7 which indicate A+,.....,AB- blood types. But when I try to query a listview according to the user select the blood group from a spinner, I get errors(stack trace is given below). Inserting data in the database doing great without giving an error.

`MainActivity` relevant code -

```
private void displayDatabaseInfo(){

        String[] projection = {
                DonorEntry.COLUMN_DONOR_NAME,
                DonorEntry.COLUMN_DONOR_MOBILE,
                DonorEntry.COLUMN_BLOOD_GROUP,
                DonorEntry.COLUMN_DONATE_DATE };

        String selection = DonorEntry.COLUMN_BLOOD_GROUP + "=?";

        String [] selectionArgs = new String[] {getString(mBloodType)};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(DonorEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                projection, selection, selectionArgs,null);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        DonorCursorAdapter adapter = new DonorCursorAdapter(this, cursor);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

`DonorCursorAdapter` relevant code -

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find individual views that we want to modify in the list item layout
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView mobileTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobileNo);
        TextView bloodTypeTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bloodType);
        TextView lastDonateTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.donateDate);

        // Find the columns of donor's attributes that we're interested in
        int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DonorEntry.COLUMN_DONOR_NAME);
        int mobileColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DonorEntry.COLUMN_DONOR_MOBILE);
        int bloodTypeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DonorEntry.COLUMN_BLOOD_GROUP);
        int lastDonateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DonorEntry.COLUMN_DONATE_DATE);

        // Read the donor attributes from the Cursor for the current pet
        String donorName = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
        String donorMobileNo = cursor.getString(mobileColumnIndex);
        String donorBloodType = cursor.getString(bloodTypeColumnIndex);
        String donorLastDonate = cursor.getString(lastDonateColumnIndex);

        // Update the TextViews with the attributes for the current pet
        nameTextView.setText(donorName);
        mobileTextView.setText(donorMobileNo);
        bloodTypeTextView.setText(donorBloodType);
        lastDonateTextView.setText(donorLastDonate);
    }
```

Stack trace

```
<code>
2019-03-02 17:25:37.140 28705-28705/com.sarkerjr.greenBlood E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sarkerjr.greenBlood, PID: 28705
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:339)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:433)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:556)
        at com.sarkerjr.greenBlood.MainActivity.displayDatabaseInfo(MainActivity.java:121)
        at com.sarkerjr.greenBlood.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:21)
        at com.sarkerjr.greenBlood.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

</code>
```

Comment: It's crashing because of `cursor.getString(bloodTypeColumnIndex)` I believe. You are storing `Integer` values in DB but trying to get String from that column index. So try changing it to `cursor.getInt()` and then use `String.valueOf()` to parse int to string.

Comment: @Ranjan I do the modification but didn't work
int donorBloodType = cursor.getInt(bloodTypeColumnIndex);
bloodTypeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(donorBloodType));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here fixed everything for you. There were a few problems.

1. `getString` was crashing. This is not the method you want to use to parse any integer, it is used to get a `resource` and you pass an `id` of that resource.
2. `CursorAdapter` needs `_id` column inside the `cursor` and when you passed `projection` array without `_id` column, your adapter was crashing. So I removed the projection and now you will get all the columns.
3. Although this was working somehow but you should not use `getString` when column value type is `INTEGER`, so I changed it to `getInt`.
4. You were directly assigning the column value to the `TextView` which was showing integers, so I created a method in `MainActivity` to get the actual values of blood types.

`MainActivity` changes -

```
private void displayDatabaseInfo() {

    String selection = DonorEntry.COLUMN_BLOOD_GROUP + "=?";

    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(mBloodType)};

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(DonorEntry.CONTENT_URI,
            null, selection, selectionArgs, null);

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

    DonorCursorAdapter adapter = new DonorCursorAdapter(this, cursor);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

// Get value of readable blood type
public String getBloodTypeString(int bloodType) {
    switch (bloodType) {
        case A_Positive:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.a_positive);
        case A_Negative:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.a_negative);
        case B_Positive:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.b_positive);
        case B_Negative:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.b_negative);
        case O_Positive:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.o_positive);
        case O_Negative:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.o_negative);
        case AB_Positive:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.ab_positive);
        case AB_Negative:
            return getResources().getString(R.string.ab_negative);
        default:
            return "UNKNOWN";

    }
}
```

`DonorCursorAdapter` changes -

```
int donorBloodType = cursor.getInt(bloodTypeColumnIndex);

String donorBloodTypeString;
    try {
        donorBloodTypeString = ((MainActivity) context).getBloodTypeString(donorBloodType);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Trying to access MainActivity method from different context");
    }

bloodTypeTextView.setText(donorBloodTypeString);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
String [] selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(mBloodType)};
```

instead of

```
String [] selectionArgs = new String[] {getString(mBloodType)};
```